# mongoDb aggregation values as key-value

Tags: mongodb, aggregation-framework

my data looks like this:
this is a doc.

```
[{
"name": "moses",
"display" : [
{"SQL commands that triggered the attack:" : ""}, 
{"Timetsamp" : "Query:"}, 
[[{ "ISODate" : "2021-03-14T17:14:58.064Z"}, "EXECUTE IMMEDIATE"],
 [{"ISODate" : "2021-03-14T17:14:58.064Z"}, "EXECUTE IMMEDIATE"],
 [{ "ISODate" : "2021-03-14T17:14:58.064Z"}, "EXECUTE IMMEDIATE"]]]
  
}]
```

how can i make it look like this:

```
{
"name": "moses"
"display" : [
{ "SQL commands" : ""}, 
{"Timetsamp" : "Query:"},
{"2021-03-14T17:14:58.064Z" : "EXECUTE IMMEDIATE"},
{"2021-03-14T17:14:58.064Z" : "EXECUTE IMMEDIATE"},
{"2021-03-14T17:14:58.064Z" : "EXECUTE IMMEDIATE"}]
}
```

is that even possible???

Comment: 1) your expected result is not a valid JSON 2) can you please show what have you tried?

Comment: so lets ignore the "iso date", ill edit the question

Answer (score 1):

You can do by using [$arrayToObject](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/arrayToObject/), like so:

```
db.collection.aggregate([
  {
    $replaceRoot: {
      newRoot: {
        "$arrayToObject": [
          [
            {
              k: "$a.ISODate",
              v: "$b"
            }
          ]
        ]
      }
    }
  }
])
```

[Mongo Playground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/nL-iOPAcpVp)

--- EDIT ---
The concept of your new request is still the same, it ain't pretty due to the nested nature of the structure.

```
db.collection.aggregate([
  {
    "$addFields": {
      display: {
        $reduce: {
          input: {
            $map: {
              input: "$display",
              as: "dis",
              in: {
                $cond: [
                  {
                    "$isArray": "$$dis"
                  },
                  {
                    $map: {
                      input: "$$dis",
                      as: "deepdis",
                      in: {
                        "$arrayToObject": [
                          [
                            {
                              k: {
                                "$arrayElemAt": [
                                  {
                                    $map: {
                                      input: {
                                        "$objectToArray": {
                                          "$arrayElemAt": [
                                            "$$deepdis",
                                            0
                                          ]
                                        }
                                      },
                                      as: "dd",
                                      in: "$$dd.v"
                                    }
                                  },
                                  0
                                ]
                              },
                              v: {
                                "$arrayElemAt": [
                                  "$$deepdis",
                                  1
                                ]
                              }
                            }
                          ]
                        ]
                      }
                    }
                  },
                  "$$dis"
                ]
              }
            }
          },
          initialValue: [],
          in: {
            "$concatArrays": [
              "$$value",
              {
                $cond: [
                  {
                    "$isArray": "$$this"
                  },
                  "$$this",
                  [
                    "$$this"
                  ]
                ]
              }
            ]
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
])
```

[Mongo Playground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/3l5A2LwQ-w3)

Comment: why do i need replaceRoot?

Comment: Because you want the result of `$arrayToObject` to be the "final result". if you use other stages, for example `$project` you would have to name the field and your results would look like:

{ fieldName: { "2021-03-14T17:14:58.064Z":  "EXECUTE IMMEDIATE" } }

Comment: ok this is only part of a doc with many fields. ive updated the questions

Comment: sure no problem, just make sure it's in the right format. currently what you pasted is not.

Comment: Slabbert any idea?

Comment: The input you provide is still not in a valid format, until you do so there's not much i can do. try putting it in Mongo playground and try to run an empty find,.

Comment: Added and edit to match the required structure. i'm warning you it ain't pretty.